# Installing azure-data-tables

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, pip, azure-http-trigger

I’m hoping to use `azure-data-tables` in my Python code. I'm working in VScode on an Azure HTTP trigger. I’ve run `pip3 install azure-data-tables` in the terminal on my Mac. However, when I import azure-data-tables in my file on VS code, it’s underlined in red and does not recognize it. Does anyone have any suggestions of what to try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try to run the code? Did it work? If it's only VSCode that doesn't recognize your imports, make sure it uses the same Python interpreter for which you installed the module. There are many many posts on SO that explain how to do this (not sure how this relates to Azure though).

Answer (score 0):

It is a possibility that you might be missing a virtual environment. You can install the `virtualenv` to your environment first and install `azure-data-tables` once again.

**Install Virtual Environment**

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

**Create Virtual Environment**

```
Python3 -m venv <Your_Virtual_Environment_Name>
```

**Activate Virtual Environment**

```
<Your_Virtual_Environment_Name>\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

**Get Requirements.txt**

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

**REFERENCES:** [virtual environment](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-create-requirements-txt-file-in-python#:%7E:text=In%20Python%20requirement.,Typically%20this%20file%20%22requirement)

Answer (score 0):

Because python package names cannot contain hyphens. Please replace the package name ( `azure-data-tables` ) imported in your code with `azure.data.tables` or `azure_data_tables`.

[image]

In addition, as mentioned above, virtual environments can help you install packages of different functions in different environments, which is convenient for code management and operation.

If multiple python environments exist on your machine, please use **CTRL + SHIFT + P** to open the command palette, type and select **Python: Select Interpreter** (or click on the interpreter version displayed in the lower right corner). Then choose the correct python interpreter.

[image]